# Converting string with UTC offset to a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

Given this string: `"Fri, 09 Apr 2010 14:10:50 +0000"` how does one convert it to a `datetime` object?

After doing some reading I feel like this should work, but it doesn't...

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> str = 'Fri, 09 Apr 2010 14:10:50 +0000'
>>> fmt = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
>>> datetime.strptime(str, fmt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 317, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
```

It should be noted that this works without a problem:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> str = 'Fri, 09 Apr 2010 14:10:50'
>>> fmt = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'
>>> datetime.strptime(str, fmt)
datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 9, 14, 10, 50)
```

But I'm stuck with `"Fri, 09 Apr 2010 14:10:50 +0000"`. I would prefer to convert exactly that without changing (or slicing) it in any way.

Comment: [`dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/)`.parser.parse` can do it in Python 2. `pip install dateutil`, and it should work from python 3.2 onwards.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It looks as if strptime doesn't always support `%z`. Python appears to just call the C function, and strptime doesn't support `%z` on your platform.

**Note:** from Python 3.2 onwards it will always work.

Comment: Beat me to it! Check out: http://bugs.python.org/issue6641

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I did try this with python2.5/2.6/3.1 on my win machine and python2.6/3.1 on my *nix, all yielded the same failure. I do wonder if %z actually does works for anyone, I'm guessing not.

Comment: it is incorrect. `strptime()` is implemented in pure Python. Unlike `strftime()`; it behaves the same on all platforms. It won't work on Python 2 on any platform.