# ValueError when using strptime to get a datetime object with timezone offset

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert a date string to a datetime object:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-07-15 13:00:00+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00:00
```

I guess there is a problem with my format string. How to fix that?

Comment: I want to test that the date string is in UTC format or not. So, i guess, ill have to keep the +00:00..right ?

Comment: You can also use time.strptime and strip the time zone format (and add it later on the datatime processing).

Comment: @Robert I don't think **"UTC format"** means something. I think your datetime string is written in ISO 8601 with UTC offset : see **isoformat([sep])** in the doc. So, I wonder what you want to do.

Answer (score 16):

How about stripping the offset?

```
dt_string = '2011-07-15 13:00:00+00:00'
new_dt = dt_string[:19]
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Or ...        new_dt = dt_string.split('+')[0]

Answer (score 6):

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-07-15 13:00:00+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
```

Comment: The "%z" format is platform dependent, it seems: [Converting string to datetime object in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609259/converting-string-to-datetime-object-in-python)

Comment: Should be `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z` (notice, no `+` before `%z`).

Answer (score -9):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-07-15 13:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 15, 13, 0)
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question; you're converting a completely different string to a datetime by dropping the timezone.