# Parse common log date string with python

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, python-2.6

### The problem:

I'm about to parse a log file in Python 2.6. Problems arose parsing the [common log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) date string into a time object:

`13/Sep/2012:06:27:18 +0200`

### What I tried already

#### Use `dateutils.parser.parse`

I already tried using `dateutils.parser.parse` but it failed parsing it with the following error:

`ValueError: unknown string format`

#### Use `time.strptime`

I tried `time.strptime` with the format string `%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z` but ran into trouble when parsing the timezone:

`ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z'`

Does anyone know, where the error is? Or is it just the wrong approach?

### Final solution

Finally I decided to use `time.strptime` with stripping off the timezone information:

```py
time.strptime(datestring[:-6], '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```

The reason don't want to use `dateutils` is that `dateutils` is way slower than `strptime` (which actually calls a C function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I see:

- `dateutil` dislikes having the time appended to the date
- the `%z` directive is not supported by your underlying C implementation (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609259/converting-string-to-datetime-object-in-python))

A quick and easy solution (though, not really elegant):

```
>>> s = '13/Sep/2012:06:27:18 +0200'
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(s.replace(':', ' ', 1))
datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 13, 6, 27, 18, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))
```

As a reminder, optional third parameter to `replace` is the [max replacement count](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Comment: it seems that %z is always supported from Python 3.2 onwards