# converting utc format to required format using python

Tags: datetime, python-2.7, time, utc

I am trying to convert UTC format date format to required format using python. Simply I have the datetime in the format(Fri Dec 07 19:06:06 +0000 2012), I need to convert this into my format(2012-12-07 19:06:06:546 +0000)

Code:

```
created_at  = "Fri Dec 07 19:06:06 +0000 2012"
d = datetime.strptime(created_at, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
date_object = d.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

result:

```
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y'
```

The below link from python bugs says its fixed but i didn understand what is fixed and in which version i can use %z

http://bugs.python.org/issue6641

I am not able to use %z . Is there any other way to handle this??

Comment: If possible you could change your Python version.  You can use %z in Python 3.2 and greater.

I've tested OP's code in Python3.4 and it works fine.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609259/converting-string-to-datetime-object-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Do it like that:

```
from datetime import datetime    
TIMESTAMP = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```