# Why doesn't my Python code accept %z as a DateTime directive?

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, strptime

I'm trying to parse the following string into a valid datetime format:

```
Wed, 10 Sep 2014 11:20:58 +0000
```

for which I use this Python code:

```
dtObject = datetime.strptime(e[attr], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

Unfortunately I get an error saying:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 317, in _str
ptime
    (bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
```

According to the [strptime() docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), `%z` should be totally correct for `UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM`.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome

Comment: the z needs to be capitalized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if `strptime` doesn't always support `%z` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2609335/2873381) answer)

Instead of `strptime`, you can use `dateutil.parser` and it works fine:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> s='Wed, 10 Sep 2014 11:20:58 +0000'  #UTC
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(s)
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 11, 20, 58, tzinfo=tzutc())


>>> s='Wed, 10 Sep 2014 11:20:58 +0100'  #ANOTHER TZ
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(s)
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 11, 20, 58, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```