# python - convert string '2015-04-11 21:23:39+0530' to datetime

Tags: python

I know how to do it using `strptime`, but how do I account for `+0530`

```
d = '2015-04-11 21:23:39+0530'
d = datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

**Note** Please dont suggest to slice `0530` off.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2609335/1673391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [iso8601](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601) lib

```
>>> import iso8601
>>> iso8601.parse_date('2015-04-11 21:23:39+0530')
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 11, 21, 23, 39, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '+05:30' datetime.timedelta(0, 19800)>)
>>> type(iso8601.parse_date('2015-04-11 21:23:39+0530'))
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider it using [`dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil)

```
from dateutil import parser
d = '2015-04-11 21:23:39+0530'
p = parser.parse(d)

>>>p
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 11, 21, 23, 39, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800))
>>>p.date()  
datetime.date(2015, 4, 11)
>>>p.time()
datetime.time(21, 23, 39)
>>>p.utcoffset()
datetime.timedelta(0, 19800) #seconds
>>>str(p.utcoffset())
'5:30:00' #UTC offset
```