# Django: Convert string to datetime object

Tags: django, python-2.7, datetime, strptime

Here is the datetime string:
`dt = '2016-04-07 23:00:00'`

I have tried `datetime.strptime(year+"-"+day+"-"+month+" "+hour+":"+mins+":"+"00", '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')` but I get this error:

> type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: You should try to create a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to datetime object in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609259/converting-string-to-datetime-object-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
from dateutil import parser



date_string = '2016-04-07 23:00:00'
date_object = parser.parse(date_string)
```

Comment: It should be noted that dateutil is a 3rd party package, and requires an install

Answer (score 0):

change

```
from datetime import datetime
```

to

```
import datetime
```

and try this. hope this helps..

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I think this is a good way to convert specific string to datetime:

```
import datetime 

dt = '2016-04-07 23:00:00'
date_time_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print((date_time_object))
print(type(date_time_object))
```