# Python: Date Conversion Error

Tags: python, sqlite, date-conversion

I'm trying to convert a string into a date format, to be later stored into an SQLite database. Below is the code line at which I'm getting an error.

```
date_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d, %Y %H:%M %Z')
```

And this is the error:

```
File "00Basic.py", line 20, in spider
    date_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d, %Y %H:%M %Z')   File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
    (data_string, format)) ValueError: time data 'Aug 19, 2016 08:13 IST' does not match format '%b %d, %Y %H %M %Z'
```

Question 1: How do I resolve this error?

Question 2: Is this the right approach for preparing to store the date in SQLite later?

Please Note: Very new to programming.

Comment: Typo: you have missed the colon in %H:%M. It is there in the example code, but missing in the error message.

Comment: I thing the problem is in the timezone, not the colon.

Comment: @JamesK edited. Thank you for pointing it out...

Comment: @EndermanAPM you are right. The problem isn't in the colon. I've tried it both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pytz`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz?) for the timezone conversion as shown:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

s = "Aug 19, 2016 08:13 IST".replace('IST', '')
print(timezone('Asia/Calcutta').localize(datetime.strptime(s.rstrip(), '%b %d, %Y %H:%M')))
#2016-08-19 08:13:00+05:30
#<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I would suggest you to use [`dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.4.1) incase you are handling multiple timezones of string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is located in the `%Z` (Time zone) part of the format.
As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) explains

```
%Z  Time zone name (empty string if the object is naive).   (empty), UTC, EST, CST
```

It looks like only UTC,EST and CST are valid. (Or it just doesn't recognize **IST**)

In order to fix this, you could use the `%z` parameter that accepts any UTC offset, like so:

```
struct_time = time.strptime("Aug 19, 2016 08:13 +0530", '%b %d, %Y %H:%M %z')
```

Update: Although this works fine in Python +3.2 it raises an exception when it's run with Python2

Comment: thanks, but this hasn't worked. I'm getting the same error again.

`ValueError: time data 'Aug 19, 2016 08:13 +530' does not match format '%b %d, %Y %H:%M %Z'`

Comment: Watch out, it's a **lowercase z**, also, the 0 (in +0530) is mandatory, the format of %z is HHMM

Comment: +z was giving me another error, `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%b %d, %Y %H:%M %z'`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, as stated by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2609335/4725649) looks like it doesn't work with python2. (And I was testing on python 3.5)